# How argument and item node work in di.xml in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, di, items, virtualtype

I just wanted to know in deeply how argument, type , virtual type and item work in di.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links:

https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-design-patterns-preferences-virtual-types/

https://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2/#magento-2-object-system

https://alanstorm.com gives you deep dive into magneto 2 architecture. Check It out.